# Learning C++ and regex - couple questions

Tags: c++, regex, string, visual-studio

I just started learning, have homework to validate password, but just looping around string and checking for matches with .find() != string::npos seems too easy, I found regex and decided to learn how to use it.

Right now the code I've got looks like:

```
string password = "ddddDDDD333####";

if ( !regex_match(password, regex(".*[A-Z].*") ) )
{
    cout << "No upper case" << endl;
}

if ( !regex_match(password, regex(".*[a-z].*")))
{
    cout << "No lower case" << endl;
}

if ( !regex_match(password, regex(".*[\\d].*")))
{
    cout << "No digit" << endl;
}
```

It works.

But that's not enough for me. I wanted to check for all characters at once, so I took this from geeksforgeeks.org:

```
(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[-+_!@#$%^&*.,?]).*$
```

Couple questions:

1. Couple threads asking about regex, answers seem to put stuff like 'matching for uppercase' in `(?=.*[A-Z]).*` format. I believe I understand what it's doing, but is there any reason if just looking for one uppercase? My solution works, anything against it? I don't care about lookahead since I'm matching only one character with anything around it.
2. This expression from geeksforgeeks, how are parenthesis treated here? Are they kinda like bool function returning true if match found?
   The way I understand it is

> (look for any[a-z])(look for any[A-Z])(etc)(etc)anything

and I understand it as:

> (true)(true)(true)(true)

now since it's using lookahead, we are at the beginning of the password, so we must match everything there is, that's why there is .* at the end. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

3. Why do they use '$'? It means 'end of the string', but any reason here?

Comment: Cant you just count characters?

Comment: My advise play around with regexes on https://regex101.com/. Its a good place to debug them before using them in your code

Comment: Hi, have you got any updates?

Answer (score 0):

(?=.*[A-Z])

This represents a look around syntax, indicating that there is no newline after the current position and matches a letter.
. means match any character except newline, * is a quantifier, means 0~n, .* is 0~n any character except newline [A-Z] means match a letter in the set from A to Z, because [A-Z] ] is not followed by a quantifier, so the default is one. This means match anything starting with "any character followed by a lowercase letter", plus .* together means zero or more occurrences of any character.

() Parentheses mean that the parentheses are regarded as a whole, and the basic units are combined into a large unit.It can indeed be understood as you said.

Regarding $, according to this [issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference#anchors):

```
By default, the match must occur at the end of the string or before \n at the end of the string; in multiline mode, it must occur before the end of the line or before \n at the end of the line.
```

It decides whether to use it or not according to each person's needs